# Getting an higher accuracy than expected for classifying the '101 object categories' data using an architecture similar to Lenet5

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, classification

I'm trying to build a model similar to Lenet5 and train on the [Caltech 101](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech101/) dataset. The expected accuracy of this baseline model is less than **60%**. But my model is reaching an accuracy of **90+%**, which I suspect should not be possible with Lenet5 for this dataset. The following code snippets show how the data is read and how my model is defined, followed by results that I obtained.

I am using [tf.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#load_using_tfdata) to load the images as shown in the Tensorflow tutorials.

```
# Obtain test(10%) and train size(90%)
test_size = round(0.1 * image_count)
train_size = image_count-test_size

# Take first 10% values as test_data
test_data = labeled_ds.take(test_size)
# Skip first 10%, and keep rest 90% data as train_data
train_data = labeled_ds.skip(test_size)

# Define np arrays to store images and labels (to be passed to the model)

train_images = np.empty((train_size,64,64,3), dtype=np.float32)
train_labels = np.empty((train_size,101,), dtype=np.bool_)
test_images = np.empty((test_size,64,64,3), dtype=np.float32)
test_labels = np.empty((test_size,101,), dtype=np.bool_)

# Iterating over train_data to seperate images and labels
for i,data in enumerate(train_data):
    train_images[i] = data[0]
    train_labels[i] = data[1]

# Iterating over test_data to seperate images and labels    
for i,data in enumerate(test_data):
    test_images[i] = data[0]
    test_labels[i] = data[1]

# Convert numpy arrays into tensors
# Perform one-hot encoding for labels (False ->0, True -> 1)
train_images = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_images)
train_labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_labels, dtype=tf.int32)
test_images = tf.convert_to_tensor(test_images)
test_labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(test_labels, dtype=tf.int32)
```

The shape of the data is:

```
Train images shape:  (7809, 64, 64, 3)
Test images shape:   (868, 64, 64, 3)
Train labels shape:  (7809, 101)
Test labels shape:   (868, 101)
```

The Lenet5 model that I am defining:

```
# Define the Lenet 5 architecture as per the description
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu', input_shape=(64, 64, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((4, 4)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((4, 4)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(1024, input_shape=(256,), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(84, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(101, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=20, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

The observed loss and accuracy values:

```
Train on 7809 samples, validate on 868 samples
Epoch 1/20
7809/7809 [==============================] - 17s 2ms/sample - loss: 3.8387 - accuracy: 0.2018 - val_loss: 3.3969 - val_accuracy: 0.2661
.
.
.
Epoch 19/20
7809/7809 [==============================] - 15s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.1205 - accuracy: 0.9679 - val_loss: 0.5456 - val_accuracy: 0.9136
Epoch 20/20
7809/7809 [==============================] - 15s 2ms/sample - loss: 0.1672 - accuracy: 0.9522 - val_loss: 0.5295 - val_accuracy: 0.9159
```

I checked to ensure that my test data is not present in the train data.

```
test_images.numpy() in train_images.numpy()
# Outputs 'False'
```

I plotted the confusion matrix to ensure model is not classifying all labels as False.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

y_pred = model.predict_classes(test_images)

y_label = []
for i in range(len(y_pred)):
    a, = np.where(test_labels[i].numpy()==1)
    y_label.append(a[0])

con_mat = tf.math.confusion_matrix(labels=y_label, predictions=y_pred)
'''
Output: con_mat = 
array([[2, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 9, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 4, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 5, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 2]], dtype=int32)
'''
```

I understand that I might have committed a mistake or have overseen a potential flaw, which could have led to high accuracy. Any leads would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that Expected Baseline Model Accuracy should be less than 60%.

Comment: This architecture for the dataset does not work well. I was working with a group of people, and everyone reached ~60% accuracy for the baseline. I figured out the mistake in my code, I will update the answer accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test data and the train data are not split properly. Using the 'take' and 'skip' method did not split the data into 2 **unique** sets. I think I have the wrong understanding of take and skip methods. Since 'most' of the test data, and not 'all' of the test data is present in the train data, the line

```
test_images.numpy() in train_images.numpy()
```

outputs False.